# How to extract part of PDF image by using PDFRenderer?

Tags: android

I am using Android PdfRenderer to extract image. I am always getting full image, though I used a matrix transformation.

Suppose I have PDF image of (0,0,500,500), I want to get part of this image, for example I want to get part of image at (100,100,200,200), the width and height of image being 100 and 100 in this case.

Below is the code I am using which is not working:

```
pdfRenderer = new PdfRenderer(parcelFileDescriptor);    
PdfRenderer.Page page =  pdfRenderer.openPage(0);    
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100,100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);    
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();    
matrix.mapRect(new RectF(100,100,200,200));    
page.render(bitmap,null,matrix, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_PRINT);
```

But this code is not working! I am always getting image from (0,0) position.

Comment: use `RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY` instead of  `RENDER_MODE_FOR_PRINT` for more have look [this](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2017/02/display-pdf-using-pdfrenderer.html)

Comment: Yes, I tried both, it didn't work. In the link you have provided they are not using any transformation, they are just getting the entire bitmap. As I mentioned getting entire bitmap is not an issue, getting part of it is the problem.